# Swap out parts of the UI when the user takes a given action

Tags: c#, wpf, navigation

I would like to have a navigation feature in my WPF application that will swap out parts of the UI when the user takes a given action (ie click a button). Putting these UI pieces in their own windows isn't really appropriate. I've been using panels and swapping them out using the `visible=true` property but it has become cumbersome to manage multiple panels in a single window.

Comment: Why not create [UserControls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc294992.aspx) and swap them in and out when you want to change.

Comment: You can restyle a tabcontrol, where each tab represents a page. If you hide the tabbar and make the tab switching by hand it should be a similar effect. Of course MarkHalls idea works aswell and might be a little bit cleaner.

Comment: Thanks to both of you. I will probably use MarkHall's method since I don't really want to use pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We did what you're trying using [Caliburn Micro](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/) [Screens & Conductors](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Screens%2c%20Conductors%20and%20Composition&referringTitle=Documentation) for navigation:

- Having a [ContentControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol.aspx) named ActiveItem on View.
- Replacing ActiveItem on ViewModel using the [ActivateItem](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Screens%2c%20Conductors%20and%20Composition&referringTitle=Documentation) Conductor.

For the swap out effect we did animate the ActiveItem using two triggers (raised from ViewModel on ActiveItem change). One trigger for the swap in and one for the swap out (what this animations do is no more than change the margin from an offset to its proper value with a little delay).

You can extend this method not only for the ActiveItem but for every control you want to swap out so I expect this'll give you an idea.